# Scoring Nutch results

Tags: nutch

I am crawling using Nutch 1.2 by providing seed links to it for travel domain. Next i am indexing using Solr 3.1. I am getting the search results in my serach engine. But now i want to score the indexed results and display them in the search engine.
I have reffered the URLS: 1) http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent which is basically for boosting the queries.
2) http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts which is for boosting the documents.
How do i boost the results at the index time and retrieve the results??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What is your criteria for boosting the results?

SOLR already does a good job at calculating a documents relevancy based on the frequency the terms are present.

What are your specific requirements that are not covered by the default set up?